# How to reuse a view in SwiftUI and fill it different data?

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, reusability

noob here.

So Im coding a basic To-Do App and I need the user to be able to edit a task he previously entered. To do this, I wish to reuse my AddTaskView in the following way: once I tap "Edit" on the Task, the AddTaskView form gets presented and populated with all the Tasks data and pressing "Save" actually updates the data, instead of adding a new Task.

Currently, my AddTaskView stores all the forms variables in @State variables which have a value by default, such as:

```
@State private var taskTitle : String = ""
```

How can I send the data to AddTaskView that is already available since the task already exists to be able to populate the appropiate fields? My understanding is I cant just set @State variables values from outside the view.

**Current AddTaskView.swift**

```
struct AddTaskView: View {
    //CoreDatas managedObjectEnvironment
    @StateObject var vm : viewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var categories : FetchedResults<Category>
    @State private var taskTitle : String = ""
    @State private var taskPriority : String = "Low"
    
    @State private var chosenCategory : String? = ""
    
    @State private var taskDate : Date = Date()
    

    let priorities = ["Low", "High"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Task info")) {
                    TextField("Task title", text: $taskTitle)
                    
                }
                Section {
                    DatePicker("Date", selection: $taskDate)
                }
                
                Section {
                    Picker(
                        selection: $taskPriority,
                        label: Text("Priority")
                    ) {
                        ForEach(self.priorities, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0).tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
                Section {
                    Picker(
                        selection: $chosenCategory,
                        label: Text("Category")
                    ) {
                        ForEach(self.categories, id: \.categoryName) { cat in
                            Text(cat.categoryName ?? "Unknown").tag(cat.id)
                        }
                    }
                }
                    
                    
                    
                
                
                Section {
                    Button("Save") {
                        self.vm.addTask(moc: self.moc, title: self.taskTitle, date: self.taskDate, priority: self.taskPriority, chosenCategory: chosenCategory!)
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Task")
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

I want to call and present this AddTaskView from another view where I have all the task info. As far as I understand, I cant just present the view such as:

```
AddTaskView(taskTitle: aTitle, taskPriority: aPriority, etc)
```

Any pointers are welcomed. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not ask a small question. I am going to recommend you go through [Apple's Introducing SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). It will give you the foundation to understand what is going on, however the TLDR is every time you change an @State var in a struct, you are getting an entirely new struct. The values in a struct are immutable, regardless of what var might imply, and you literally make a new struct and put it in the old one's place.

And to answer your question as to presenting the view struct, yes, that would work. So would `AddTaskView()` the way you have your struct set up, though it wouldn't show much. Go hit the tutorial. It is well worth the time.